# Unintended behavior: Subtraction between null values results in '0'

Tags: mysql, sql

When either one of the field is `NULL`, I want the returned value to be `NULL` as well.  I have also tried reversing the logic: `is not null`.  Still the same results.

**MySQL code:**

```
(case
            when
                ((`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_received` is not null)
                    and (`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted` is not null))
            then
                (cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_received`
                    as signed) - cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted`
                    as signed))
            else NULL
        end) AS `received_forecasted_dif`
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What happened when you did `SELECT total_samples_forecasted - total_samples_received AS received_forecasted_dif`?  Using null in arithmetic should always yield `NULL`.

Comment: Try using: `CASE WHEN ( (total_samples_received IS NULL) OR (total_samples_forecasted IS NULL) ) THEN NULL ELSE ...`

Comment: Please show the rest of your query. That part of your code should be working as is, so there must be something else that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I found the source of the problem... The raw source of those 'null' fields actually contained junk strings.  So I used regex to search for valid numbers.

`(case
            when ((`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted` regexp '^-?[0-9]+$') = 0) then NULL
            else cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted`
                as signed)
        end) AS `total_samples_forecasted``

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working, but you don't need the `case`.  Whenever one of the values is `NULL`, the expression should be `NULL`:

```
(cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_received` as signed) -
 cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted` as signed))
) AS `received_forecasted_dif`
```

I wonder if your problem is that the value is actually `'NULL'` rather than `NULL`.  That is, a string value rather than a real NULL.  MySQL will treat the string as `0` in the arithmetic.

You can fix this by doing:

```
(case when `creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_received` <> 'NULL' and
           `creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted` <> 'NULL'
      then (cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_received` as signed) -
            cast(`creative_stg_sample_tracking_raw`.`total_samples_forecasted` as signed))
           )
      else NULL
end) AS `received_forecasted_dif`
```

Comment: The `NULL`s in the GUI output do look like real `NULL`s (shaded), but you're right on, it ought to work.